# Can't assign to literal python error

Tags: python, python-3.x, literals

I need to make a program that prompts the user for points received on a "quiz" (0-5). Then give them a grade back based on the scale of 5 = A, 4 = B, 3 = C, etc. When I try to assign the grades to the numbers, it says `Cannot assign to literal`.

```
grade = eval(input("How many points did you receive? "))

grade = str(A, B, C, D, F)

1, 0 = F
2 = D
3 = C
4 = B
5 = A


print("The grade you received was a(n)", str(grade),".")
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve], not just a vague description.

Comment: Can you show your code and full error trace? It will help us to figure out what is going on.

Comment: It does not let me upload a picture and when i paste code is looks funny, thats the best i can do unless anyone has a better idea!! thanks!!

Comment: If you indent all your code by four extra spaces, it will create a code sample.

Comment: Okay thanks i see now, there is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by trying to assign a value to an integer. The integer itself is a literal, just a value. You cannot assign to it like a variable.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18716787/4539233) answer says:

> The left hand side of the = operator needs to be a variable. What you're doing here is telling python: "You know the number one? Set it to the inputted string.". 1 is a literal number, not a variable. 1 is always 1, you can't "set" it to something else.

Because of this, python is saying to you "I can't change what 1 is."

---

A way to refactor it to work would be to assign the input to a variable, then look at the value of the variable. There are two ways to do this.

1. A dictionary (considered better practice, because of brevity and sustainability)
2. A stack of if statements

With a dictionary:

```
score = str(input("Enter the grade: "))

grades = {0: 'F',
          1: 'F',
          2: 'D',
          3: 'C',
          4: 'B',
          5: 'A'}

print(grades[score])
```

It just prints the letter grade associated with the score in the dictionary.

With `if`'s:

```
score = str(input("Enter the grade: "))

if score == 0 or score == 1:
    print('F')

elif score == 2:
    print('D')

elif score == 3:
    print('C')

elif scoe == 4:
    print('B')

else:
    print('A')
```

The way this works is pretty clear. I don't recommend using it, though, since it is horribly tedious to write and longer than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly trying to set `5 = A` etc, you can use a dictionary which relates the string of each numerical character to the string letter grade. Although this does not directly answer your question, this is probably the best way to associate numbers with their grade equivalents.

```
def score():
    score_dict = {'0' : 'F', '1' : 'F', '2' : 'D', '3' : 'C', '4' : 'B', '5' : 'A'}
    score = input('Enter a score:')
    if score in score_dict.keys():
        print("The grade you received was a(n) ",score_dict[score],".")
    else:
        print("Invalid score.")
```

Edit: Now that you've updated your question with code, I'm not sure if this is what you need. This is a working solution, but it doesn't work quite the same way as what you have. I'll leave it here just in case you need a working solution, and not just a solution to your question.

Comment: This will fix their problem, but not help them in the future, or help any people who see this in the future. Simply giving them code that will work with no explanation is ultimately useless.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman So should I delete this solution? I posted this before they included code so it was the best I could do under the circumstances. I believe a dictionary is the only way of assigning a number to a character, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Or edit it to answer the question. Either way.

Comment: Thank you both!! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman Thanks for explaining what I did wrong and expanding your answer to include the use of dictionaries.