# Problem in coding argument to create output

Tags: python

I need to make this equation into 9. An example of the following can be seen below:

## a^2-b^2 = (a+b)*(a-b)

## 5^2 - 4^2 = (5+4)(5-4) = 9

and the code must be in multiplier using

## print(mult_numbers(add_numbers(5,4), sub_numbers(5,4)))

```
def add_numbers(a, b):
    result = a + b
    return result

def sub_numbers(a, b):
     Write code to return sum of a and b
    result =  None #Replace None with your code
    return result
```

Can someone help me to re-write the code?

```
def add_numbers(5, 4):
    result = 5 + 4
    return result

def sub_numbers(5, 4):
    # Write code to return sum of a and b
    result =  5-4
    return result
print(mult_numbers(add_numbers(5,4), sub_numbers(5,4)))
```

I am receiving :

## File "", line 1

```
def add_numbers(5, 4):
                ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Learn about parameter passing in Python. You can use `def add_numbers(a, b): ` and call the function with the values you need like `add_numbers(5, 4)`.

Comment: You are trying to assign values to literals. Same as this: `1 = 'something'`.. can't do it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716564/python-cant-assign-to-literal

Comment: Remember that the names you include in the brackets when defining a function are variables that are assigned values when you call that function.

Comment: You need to **call** the `add_numbers(a, b)` function something like this `result = add_numbers(5, 4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write the numbers as function parameters, you have to define variables to hold your arguments, here's the correct code:

```
def add_numbers(n1, n2):
    result = n1 + n2
    return result

def sub_numbers(n1, n2):
    # Write code to return sum of a and b
    result =  n1-n2
    return result
print(mult_numbers(add_numbers(5,4), sub_numbers(5,4)))
```